# Using multiprocessing causes MemoryError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have some code that is supposed to take a large list of data (stored in a variable called `stabiliser_states`) and do some analysis on every subset of size `set_size`. Since the number of subsets can get very large, I've been trying to use the multiprocessing module to parallelise the code. However, for the data that I'm actually interested in, running the code eventually leads to a MemoryError.

Here's the part of the code that has been parallelised. The function `check_lin_dep` does the data analysis and seems to be working fine.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import combinations

...

pool = mp.Pool()
lin_dep_iter = pool.starmap(
    check_lin_dep,
    ((comb[1], n, set_size, comb[0]) for comb in \
         enumerate(combinations(stabiliser_states, set_size))),
    chunksize=1000
)
pool.close()
```

For the data which leads to the MemoryError, the length of `stabiliser_states` is about 37000, so for `set_size = 2` there are about 700 million combinations. My understanding is that starmap should be using an iterable instead of a list, but I suppose that the error maybe suggests that the program is trying to store the combinations (or another huge list) in memory somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purposes, I discovered that the real problem is that starmap converts the args generator to a list behind the scenes ([How to use a generator as an iterable with Multiprocessing map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708312/how-to-use-a-generator-as-an-iterable-with-multiprocessing-map-function)). This is what was causing the MemoryError. I was able to solve this by simply using imap instead of starmap.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it already been answered here:
[Python Multiprocessing.Pool lazy iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318936/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration)

Comment: Yes, I was about to post this myself.  That line of code is a tuple comprehension, so it's creating an enormous tuple before any work is done.

Comment: So I've double-checked and I believe that line *does* create a generator rather than a tuple, although I've changed it anyway since it is kind of hard to read. After doing some more research, it seems that the real problem is that starmap converts the generator to a list behind the scenes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708312/how-to-use-a-generator-as-an-iterable-with-multiprocessing-map-function)... Is there a different function I can use that won't do this?

Comment: don't have on from the top of my head. but I found someone solved a similar problem: https://newbedev.com/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration or in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318936/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration